# BIRT Summing rows after 10 rows into others

Tags: birt

I have a requirement to club all row after 5th row into others while displaying in report design.

Table and Values-
A 10
B 20
C 10
D 20
E 10
F 10
G 20
H 10

This is how I want to display in birt grid -
A 10
B 20
C 10
D 20
E 10
Others 40

Comment: I don't know what "club" means in that context. Not sure I fully understand the question. This just a running (cumulative) total that is suppressed on first rows?

Comment: I would rephrase and say, I want to group any row after 5th row.
I have a display limitation in the birt report design and can only display 6 rows of data. The user want to show 5 items and any more than that should be grouped into others.

Comment: OK, I see now `Others 40` being the roll up... Sorry I don't know the answer.